# If Statements VBA ACCESS 2010

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-access-2010

When using a

```
If Then
'Do Something
Else If
'Do Something
End If
```

If the first and second condition is true would it execute just the first or both?

for some reason when i have this code:

```
Dim Report As String

If (DateRange_Pro_TotalCount > 0) Then

        Dim DateRange_Pro_ReportStr As String

        DateRange_Pro_ReportStr = "Total Referrals: " & DateRange_Pro_TotalCount & vbNewLine _

        Report = Report & DateRange_Pro_ReportStr

    ElseIf (DateRange_InPro_TotalCount > 0) Then

        Dim DateRange_InPro_ReportStr As String

        DateRange_InPro_ReportStr = "Total Referrals: " & DateRange_InPro_TotalCount & vbNewLine _

        Report = Report & DateRange_InPro_ReportStr

End If

'next statement prints report variable to textBox
```

This statement only executes the first condition even though both conditions are true. I changed 'Else If' to 'End If' and 'If' ( two diff. conditional statments instead of one statement with two conditions) and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, it will only execute the first block

From [IF-THEN-ELSE Statement (VBA)](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php)

```
If condition_1 Then
    result_1

 ElseIf condition_2 Then
   result_2
 ...
 ElseIf condition_n Then
    result_n

 Else
   result_else

 End If
```

> condition_1 to condition_n are evaluated in the order listed. **Once a
>   condition is found to be true, the IF-THEN-ELSE statement will execute
>   the corresponding code and not evaluate the conditions any further.**
>
> result_1 to result_n is the code that is executed once a condition is
>   found to be true.

Answer (score 1):

`If...ElseIf...EndIf` does exactly what it suggests in English:

- `If` the first condition is true, execute the first block.
- `Else`, `if` the second condition is true, execute the second block.

In your case, you want two separate if statements; they will both be independently evaluated regardless of the result of the other condition.